# How to open/close Drawer from another component in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a mobile app which has components base structure. For showing Drawer globally i've implemented it in my **Home.js** like code below, but my drawer toggler must be in my Header component that inside my Container component.

How it possible to send instance of main drawer to **Header** component and control opening/closing status?

Home.js code:

```
class Home extends Component {


render() {
    const drawerContent = <DrawerComp />;

    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={comp => {
          this.drawer = comp;
        }}
        drawerWidth={250}
        drawerContent={drawerContent}
        type={Drawer.types.Overlay}
        drawerPosition={Drawer.positions.Right}
        maskAlpha={0.05}
        onDrawerOpen={() => {
          console.log("Drawer is opened !");
        }}
        onDrawerClose={() => {
          console.log("Drawer is closed !");
          this.props.dispatch(displayDrawer());
        }}
        >

        <Container>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
          <Header drawer={this.drawer} />

          <TouchableHighlight
            underlayColor="#118d95"
            onPress={this.handleDisplayDrawer}
          >
            <Text>Open Right Drawer</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </Container>
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

Header component:

```
class Header extends Component {
   handleDisplayDrawer = () => {
      //
   };

   render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableHighlight
         onPress={this.handleDisplayDrawer}
         style={styles.colSmall}
         underlayColor="#ffffff"
       >
         <Image
           style={styles.icon}
           resizeMode="contain"
           source={require("./images/icon-menu.png")}
         />
       </TouchableHighlight>


     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried to send drawer via header props but was undefined. then deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass function to `Header` component which calls that function when you want.

```
class Home extends Component {
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer.toggle(); // edit this according to drawer library
  }

  render() {
    <Header onMenuPress={this.toggleDrawer} />
  }
}

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onMenuPress}>
      <Image />
    </TouchableHighlight>
  }
}
```

Comment: So how can  implement onMenuPress in my header to toggling the drawer?

Comment: I have updated the example how to call `onMenuPress` in `Header`. Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks. that was the answer just **this.drawer.toggle();** doesn't exists in library that i'm using.

Comment: Yeah that is just an example because you did not tell what library you are using :P

Answer (score 0):

You can write a setDrawerState function in Drawer.js. that actually closes the drawer. Something like

```
setDrawerState(isOpen) => {
this.setState({
 isOpen,
})
}

In Your home.js , you already have ref to drawer component .
you can write following function.
close = () => {
this.drawer.setDrawerState(false)
}
open = () => {
this.drawer.setDrawerState(true)
}

<Header
  close={this.close}
  open={this.open}
 />
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to change drawer original library.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled alot to find a solution so, If you are using custom header component then my suggestion is to render customer header in each screen and toggle it using:-

```
navigation.openDrawer();
```